# setting up facebook api login with php authorization

Tags: facebook, api

Currently I have the facebook api working. I have included scope string to grab extra permissions.

I am lacking the ability to authorize access to restricted pages on my site. How can I set it up so when facebook logs the user in they are also logged in to my site?

```
<?php 
include 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '****************',
  'secret' => '****************',
  'cookie' => true
));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'user_checkins, user_location, friends_checkins')
  );
  echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}

?>


<h3>Welcome to your profile</h3>
      <?php
      echo $user_profile['first_name'];
      echo ' <span>&nbsp;</span> ';
      echo $user_profile['last_name'];
      ?>
```

This is the basic php api from facebook.

Comment: Please show the code you have already.

Comment: I added the fb php api code. I hope this helps. I dont have an example of my answering my questions... cause I do not know where to begin. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are endless ways to do this, but you should just be able to place the private content inside of an IF block checking for the logged in Facebook user:

```
<?php if ($user): // Show the private content ?>
      <h3>Welcome to your profile</h3>
      <?php
      echo $user_profile['first_name'];
      echo ' <span>&nbsp;</span> ';
      echo $user_profile['last_name'];
      ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```